# Qt - How to convert a number into QChar

Tags: qt, numbers, char

I have a qulonglong variable and I need to convert it into QChar.
For example, from number 65 I should get 'A'.
Or if there is a solution to make that directly into QString would be good too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qhat you need is the [`QChar`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#QChar-7) constructor.

```
QChar c((short) n);
```

Notice that `QChar` provides 16 bit characters:

> The QChar class provides a 16-bit Unicode character. In Qt, Unicode
>   characters are 16-bit entities without any markup or structure. This
>   class represents such an entity. It is lightweight, so it can be used
>   everywhere. Most compilers treat it like a unsigned short.

[`qlonglong`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qlonglong-typedef) is an 64 bit integer so you should be very careful with the conversion to `short`

Comment: I think that those 16 bit will be enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
qlonglong i = 65;
QString((char)i);
```

Or see the docs [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromAscii).

Comment: Though you might want to do some bounds checking on your `qlonglong` before you cast it down to a `char`.